# Load image from camera and gallery in Android 8.1.0 Mi A1 not working

Tags: android, image, camera

I need to take a picture from the camera and gallery. I have already done it perfectly for other Android devices except for the Xiaomi A1 Android version 8.1.0. The camera and taking the picture from the gallery and cropping it is not working: "com.android.camera.action.CROP".

Image cropping code:

```
 private void performCrop(Uri picUri) {
        try {

            Intent cropIntent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");
            //cropIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
            //indicate image type and Uri
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
                cropIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
                Uri contentUri = null;
                try {
                    contentUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(MainApplication.applicationContext, "com.kchannels.robi.circle.app.fileprovider", new File(new URI(picUri.toString())));
                } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                cropIntent.setDataAndType(contentUri, "image/*");
            } else {
                //intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(newFile), type);
                cropIntent.setDataAndType(picUri, "image/*");
            }

            //set crop properties
            cropIntent.putExtra("crop", "true");
            //indicate aspect of desired crop
            //cropIntent.putExtra("aspectX", 4);
            //cropIntent.putExtra("aspectY", 3);

            cropIntent.putExtra("aspectX", 4);
            cropIntent.putExtra("aspectY", 4);

            //indicate output X and Y
            //cropIntent.putExtra("outputX", 256);
            //cropIntent.putExtra("outputY", 192);

            cropIntent.putExtra("outputX", 256);
            cropIntent.putExtra("outputY", 256);

            //cropIntent.putExtra("outputX", 768);
            //cropIntent.putExtra("outputY", );
            //retrieve data on return
            cropIntent.putExtra("return-data", true);
            //start the activity - we handle returning in onActivityResult

            List<ResolveInfo> list = MainApplication.applicationContext.getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(cropIntent, 0);

            Intent i = new Intent(cropIntent);
            ResolveInfo res = list.get(0);
            i.setComponent(new ComponentName(res.activityInfo.packageName, res.activityInfo.name));
            cropIntent = i;
            this.crop = true;
            this.cropIntent = cropIntent;

            return;

            //_a.startActivityForResult(cropIntent, PIC_CROP);

        } catch (ActivityNotFoundException anfe) {
            //display an error message
          //  String errorMessage = "Your device dont support crop action";
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(_a, anfe.getMessage() , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.show();
        }
```

Show camera:

```
Intent captureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            //we will handle the returned data in onActivityResult
            fileUri = getActivity().getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values); // store content values
            captureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri);
            uploadfile.setFileUri(fileUri);
            startActivityForResult(captureIntent, UploadApi.CAMERA_CAPTURE);
```

Comment: my problem resolved by using this library 
https://github.com/ArthurHub/Android-Image-Cropper

Comment: Post the error what error you had face while running this code ?

Comment: Your device dont support crop action

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URI scheme is not "file" and another one Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URI scheme is not "file"

Comment: contentUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(MainApplication.applicationContext, "com.kchannels.robi.circle.app.fileprovider", new File(new URI(picUri.toString())));
when load image from gellary its working but when take image from it shows Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URI scheme is not "file" and another one Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URI scheme is not "file" but when Xiaomi A1 do that same think every time it shows. URI scheme is not "file" and another one Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URI scheme is not "file"

Comment: did you find the solution? I am having a user with a Redmi 8a that the apps restart when taking the picture and send it to a crop implementation.